# Which of the HTTP response codes can be expected if we have an error while creating and inserting value into a database?

Tags: api, http, http-response-codes

Which of the HTTP response codes can be expected if we have an error while creating and inserting value into a database?

Comment: Who is at fault?   If insert failed because of an operational error, then respond with 500.  If insert failed because of a problem with the request, then 4xx.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

Forbidden
[403 Forbidden.](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#:%7E:text=4%20403%20Forbidden,request%20SHOULD%20NOT%20be%20repeated.)

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
> Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated.